# Three.js Camera - How to follow an object from behind, and rotate alongside with it?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera

I have my little spaceship here. It moves up/down/left/right, and rotates. When moving up, it rotates, giving it a `U` curve, where it can end up upside down

I'm trying to get the camera to follow it, and succumb to it's rotations as well. So when the ship is upside down, the camera is upside down as well.

**The camera should be in a position where the ship is always pointing straight and forward**

This is the code I have - camera follow's an object fine, but doesn't rotate alongside with it

```
function updateCamera(){
    var offset = new THREE.Vector3(spaceship.position.x + 20, spaceship.position.y + 6, spaceship.position.z);
            
    camera.position.lerp(offset, 0.2);
            
    camera.lookAt(spaceship.position);
}
```

Camera following, but doesn't rotate along with the ship:

[image]

Camera following, but doesn't rotate along with the ship:

[image]

I want the camera to always view and follow the `spaceship` at this angle (no matter the position/rotation of the spaceship):

[image]

Comment: A different approach is a pattern like this: `camera.position.set( 0, 6, - 20 ); camera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 ); spaceship.add( camera );`

Comment: @WestLangley this method makes the camera unbearably shakey. Is there a way to smoothen it out?

Comment: It shouldn't. Do not call updateCamera() with this alternate technique...

Comment: @WestLangley probably some kind of problem with my code, I'll look for it. Last question please, is there a way to add a delay to the camera using this method? Like when the spaceship moves, then the camera waits about 300 millisecond then follows it? That would be perfect. Also, write in comment as answer so I can accept your answer

Comment: Actually, I did not answer the question you asked, so I will not post it as an answer -- but you can if you want...

Comment: Not tried, but to simulate a delay, add a dummy camera, instead: `dummyCamera.position.set( 0, 6, - 20 ); dummyCamera.lookAt( 0, 0, 0 ); spaceship.add( dummyCamera );` ...

Comment: .. then `dummyCamera.getWorldPosition( pTarget ); dummyCamera.getWorldQuaternion( qTarget );` and `lerp()` real camera position toward `pTarget` and `slerp()` real camera quaternion toward `qTarget`. Again, I have not tried this, though.

Comment: @WestLangley `pTarget` being the ship's position, or a separate new variable?

Comment: @WestLangley if it solves the problem, then technically you have answered it :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232877/discussion-between-westlangley-and-vardan-betikyan).